# Filter out nodes from XML payload

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

Using:
Mule 3.9, Dataweave 1.0

I am trying to filter out unwanted nodes in a XML document by the value of a child field (TestData.Orders.Items.ItemCategory).

In my example there are 3 Items, I need to remove Items that do not contain the value 'CAT1' in the ItemCategory field. The same goes for the Documents, but it should be the same solution.

```
<TestData>
    <Orders uniqueId="6000:1234">
        <CoverPage>
            <Number>CPN-0001</Number>
        </CoverPage>
        <Items referentId="9000:100:10">
            <ItemNumber>AAA-0001</ItemNumber>
            <ItemCategory>CAT2|CAT3</ItemCategory>
            <Description>Just another description</ODescription>
        </Items>
        <Items referentId="9000:200:20">
            <ItemNumber>AAA-0002</ItemNumber>
            <ItemCategory>CAT2|CAT1|CAT3</ItemCategory>
            <OldItemDescription>Just another description</OldItemDescription>
        </Items>
        <Items referentId="9000:300:30">
            <ItemNumber>AAA-0003</ItemNumber>
            <ItemCategory>CAT2|CAT3</ItemCategory>
            <OldItemDescription>Just another description</OldItemDescription>
        </Items>
        <Page2/>
    </Orders>

    <Documents uniqueId="9000:100:10">
        <Title>
            <Number>AAA-0001</Number>
            <DocumentCategory>CAT2|CAT3</DocumentCategory>
        </Title>
        <ChangeHistory>
            <RelDate>2019-12-10T01:29:28Z</RelDate>
            <Number>CHN-0001</Number>
        </ChangeHistory>
    </Documents>
    <Documents uniqueId="9000:100:20">
        <Title>
            <Number>AAA-0002</Number>
            <DocumentCategory>CAT2|CAT1|CAT3</DocumentCategory>
        </Title>
        <ChangeHistory>
            <RelDate>2019-12-10T01:29:28Z</RelDate>
            <Number>CHN-0001</Number>
        </ChangeHistory>
    </Documents>
    <Documents uniqueId="9000:100:30">
        <Title>
            <Number>AAA-0003</Number>
            <DocumentCategory>CAT2|CAT3</DocumentCategory>
        </Title>
        <ChangeHistory>
            <RelDate>2019-12-10T01:29:28Z</RelDate>
            <Number>CHN-0001</Number>
        </ChangeHistory>
    </Documents>
</TestData>
```

So I need the example above to be transformed into the example below, only keeping the Items and Documents that contain the value 'CAT1' in the ItemCategory field.

```
<TestData>
    <Orders uniqueId="6000:1234">
        <CoverPage>
            <Number>CPN-0001</Number>
        </CoverPage>
        <Items referentId="9000:200:20">
            <ItemNumber>AAA-0002</ItemNumber>
            <ItemCategory>CAT2|CAT1|CAT3</ItemCategory>
            <OldItemDescription>Just another description</OldItemDescription>
        </Items>
        <Page2/>
    </Orders>

    <Documents uniqueId="9000:100:20">
        <Title>
            <Number>AAA-0002</Number>
            <DocumentCategory>CAT2|CAT1|CAT3</DocumentCategory>
        </Title>
        <ChangeHistory>
            <RelDate>2019-12-10T01:29:28Z</RelDate>
            <Number>CHN-0001</Number>
        </ChangeHistory>
    </Documents>
</TestData>
```

**Filter and rebuild strategy:**

I tried an approach where I made 2 filter functions (one for Items and 1 for Documents) and then rebuild the document from scratch,

Filter:

```
%function cleanItems(items) items filter ((lower $.ItemCategory contains 'cat1') == true)
%function cleanDocuments(docs) docs filter ((lower $.ns0#Title.DocumentCategory contains 'cat1') == true)
```

Rebuild from scratch:

```
{
    TestData @(xmlns: "http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2014/08/"): {
        ChangeOrders @(uniqueId: payload.ns0#TestData.ns0#Orders.@uniqueId): {
        }
        ++ payload.ns0#TestData.*ns0#Orders.ns0#CoverPage
        ++ cleanItems(payload.ns0#TestData.*ns0#Orders.*ns0#Items)
        ++ payload.ns0#TestData.*ns0#Orders.ns0#PageTwo
    } 
    ++ cleanDocuments(payload.ns0#TestData.*ns0#Documents)
}
```

It basically works, but I loose the node attributes 'xmlns' and 'xmlns:xsd' and 'xmlns:xsi' and 'xsi:schemaLocation'.

I then tried to put in the missing attributes (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-cookbook-insert-attribute) whith this @(xmlns: "http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2014/08/") but if the atribute contains a colon ':' it fails, and I don't know how to escape the colon. Another issue with building it from scratch is that I can only put in nodes that I know about (there is no XSD for the document).

Since the functionality I am trying to make is part of a much larger flow, I needs to leave the XML payload 100% the same (but without the unwanted nodes), or it will cause issues.

So I am thinking of an approach where the unwanted nodes can just be removed from the document so I don't have to rebuild it from scratch.

I hope you can help, I tried everything that I can think of.

Comment: I am looking at your input data and I am comparing with the code you provided--nowhere do I see namespaces in the input data.  I suspect you need to revise the input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, if the namespaces are part of the input they should be preserved in the output.  I could potentially make it a little simpler but its late and I am brain dead ATM.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml

%var testKey = (k,v) ->     k as :string match {
    "Items"     -> ($ != "Items" or ($ == "Items" and (v.ItemCategory contains "CAT1"))),
    "Documents" -> ($ != "Documents" or ($ == "Documents" and (v.Title.DocumentCategory contains "CAT1"))) ,
    default     -> true
}

%var traverse = (ds) -> ds match {
    :object -> $ mapObject ( (v,k) -> (
        {((k): traverse(v)) when testKey(k,v)}
    ) ),
    default -> $
}
---
traverse(payload)
```